# Slider: How to translate mousemove (click and hold) on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, mousemove

I have created a form that uses http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/ to create a slider for input values and it works great. My problem however, is that it's not fantastic on a touch device as it listens for a mousemove event.

In the script I found this bit that should be related to the mouse events it's listening for:

```
this.track.mousedown(function(e) {
return _this.trackEvent(e);
});
if (this.settings.highlight) {
this.highlightTrack.mousedown(function(e) {
  return _this.trackEvent(e);
});
}
this.dragger.mousedown(function(e) {
if (e.which !== 1) {
  return;
}
_this.dragging = true;
_this.dragger.addClass("dragging");
_this.domDrag(e.pageX, e.pageY);
return false;
});
$("body").mousemove(function(e) {
if (_this.dragging) {
  _this.domDrag(e.pageX, e.pageY);
  return $("body").css({
    cursor: "pointer"
  });
}
}).mouseup(function(e) {
if (_this.dragging) {
  _this.dragging = false;
  _this.dragger.removeClass("dragging");
  return $("body").css({
    cursor: "auto"
  });
}
});
```

By all means, I'm no jQuery or Javascript expert. Do you know if it's possible to add touch functionality to the slider? And help is highly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this, by adding jQuery mobile:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

and then modify the part of the code I pasted in before with this:

```
  this.track.bind('vmousedown',function(e) {
    return _this.trackEvent(e);
  });
  if (this.settings.highlight) {
    this.highlightTrack.bind('vmousedown',function(e) {
      return _this.trackEvent(e);
    });
  }
  this.dragger.bind('vmousedown',function(e) {
    _this.dragging = true;
    _this.dragger.addClass("dragging");
    _this.domDrag(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    return false;
  });
  $("body").bind('vmousemove',function(e) {
    if (_this.dragging) {
      _this.domDrag(e.pageX, e.pageY);
      return $("body").css({
        cursor: "pointer"
      });
    }
  }).bind('vmouseup',function(e) {
    if (_this.dragging) {
      _this.dragging = false;
      _this.dragger.removeClass("dragging");
      return $("body").css({
        cursor: "auto"
      });
    }
  });
```

Now it works on mobile as well :-)